# Adding a column that counts sequential numbers

Tags: r

I would like to add a column that counts the number of consecutive values.  Most of what I am seeing on here is how to count duplicate values (1,1,1,1,1) and I would like to count a when the number goes up by 1 ( 5,6,7,8,9).  The ID column is what I have and the counter column is what I would like to create.  Thanks!

```
ID Counter  
5  1  
6  2  
7  3  
8  4  
10 1  
11 2  
13 1  
14 2  
15 3  
16 4
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of valid output?

Comment: `sequence(rle(c(0, cumsum(!diff(df$Counter) %in% 0:1)))$lengths)` could work

Comment: Try `ave(dat$ID,cumsum(c(FALSE,diff(dat$ID)!=1)),FUN=seq_along)`.

Comment: What would be the desired output for a vector of type `1 1 1 1 2 3 4`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg it would be the same as the origional.  1 1 1 1 2 3 4 only the last 4 are different.  if it was 2 2 2 2 3 4 5 the desired output would still be 1 1 1 1 2 3 4

Comment: So what the following sentence means, and I quote you "*Most of what I am seeing on here is how to count duplicate values (1,1,1,1,1)*", I understood that you want to count duplicated values too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the `dplyr` package. The idea is to calculate the difference between each number to create a grouping column, and then assign counter to each group.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Diff = ID - lag(ID, default = 0),
         Group = cumsum(Diff != 1)) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Counter = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Diff, -Group)
dat2
# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#       ID Counter
#    <int>   <int>
#  1     5       1
#  2     6       2
#  3     7       3
#  4     8       4
#  5    10       1
#  6    11       2
#  7    13       1
#  8    14       2
#  9    15       3
# 10    16       4
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID
5   
6  
7  
8  
10  
11  
13  
14  
15  
16",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

A loop version is simple:

```
for (i in 2:length(ID)) 
  if (diff(ID)[i-1] == 1) 
    counter[i] <- counter[i-1] +1
  else
    counter[i] <- 1
```

But this loop will perform very bad for n > 10^4! I'll try to think of a vector-solution!

Comment: You can calcualte `diff(ID)` outside the loop instead of calculating it for each `i`.

Comment: There are over 1 million rows so that would be much appreciated, thanks for your help!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yeah you are right! Found a super fast vector solution, will post it in a second!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent when i tried to do that it gave me an error saying replacement has 1564109 rows and data has 1564110. I think i could be because it cant calculate the first one? is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @user10256905 yes, the first value must be 1! But check out my other answer for a more efficient algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

You can using

```
s=df$ID-shift(df$ID)
s[is.na(s)]=1   
ave(s,cumsum(s!=1),FUN=seq_along)
[1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This one makes use solely of highly efficient vector-arithmetic. Idea goes as follows:

1.take the cumulative sum of the differences of ID

2.subtract the value if jump is bigger than one

```
cum <- c(0, cumsum(diff(ID)))  # take the cumulative difference of ID
ccm <- cum * c(1, (diff(ID) > 1))  # those with jump > 1 will remain its value

# subtract value with jump > 1 for all following numbers (see Link for reference)
# note: rep(0, n) is because ccm[...] starts at first non null value

counter <- cum - c(rep(0, which(diff(dat) != 1)[1]),
                   ccm[which(ccm != 0)][cumsum(ccm != 0)]) + 1
enter code here
```

*Notes*:

- Reference for highliy efficient fill-function by nacnudus: [Fill in data frame with values from rows above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554741/fill-in-data-frame-with-values-from-rows-above)
- Restriction: Id must be monotonically increasing

That should deal with your millions of data efficiently!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
  breaks <- c(which(diff(ID)!=1), length(ID))
  x <- c(breaks[1], diff(breaks))
  unlist(sapply(x, seq_len))
```